# Linq query to get all posts with more than X comments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm building a small blog application with asp mvc5.
I'm trying to add a search option that uses LINQ to SQL query.
my tables are like this:

```
Posts:PostID(int), Title(nvarchar), Body(nvarchar)

Comments:CommentID(int), Comment(nvarchar), PostID(int)
```

The PostID from the Comments table associates the comment object with a specific post.

I'm trying to write a query that given a number X will return all posts with X or more comments.

Is it possible to do in one query?

Thanks, David

Comment: LINQ to what?  And what have you tried?

Comment: `db.Posts.Where(p => p.Comments.Count() > x)`

Comment: Do you use entityframework (what version) or linq-to-sql or whatever?

Comment: Thanks David, what you wrote solved my problem

Comment: @David Please post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what we *don't* know is your model structure or what LINQ provider you're using.  However, *in general*, with a well-structured domain model, you'd simply do this:

```
db.Posts.Where(p => p.Comments.Count() > x)
```

Given an integer variable `x`, this should evaluate to the collection of `Post` objects in which there are more than `x` comments.